# Python Jupyter Anaconda, can't import cv or geopy

Tags: python, import, anaconda, jupyter

I've been able to install both modules using pip install, in a command window, without any issues (windows 7 64). When I try to import either in Jupyter, I receive the following error message:

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-305887a710d6> in <module>()
----> 1 import cv

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv'
```

About Jupyter Notebook:

```
    Server Information:
You are using Jupyter notebook.

The version of the notebook server is 5.0.0 and is running on:
Python 3.6.3 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Oct 15 2017, 03:27:45) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]

Current Kernel Information:
Python 3.6.3 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Oct 15 2017, 03:27:45) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 6.1.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.
```

I'm very new to python/programming, if that wasn't obvious already. Thx.

Comment: what happens in a command line when you do `python -c "import cv"`?

Comment: File "<ipython-input-8-267a6bfbe5c7>", line 1
    python -c "import cv"
                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: not from ipython command line. I meant the windows command line. The one you get when you run cmd.exe

Comment: Are you referring to the command prompt window (dos prompt)?

Comment: yes that's what I mean

Comment: "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement cv (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for cv

Comment: sorry, bad day I guess. That was the response for "pip install cv"...

Comment: to your original question, Traceback (most recent call last):   File "(string)", line 1 in (module)   ModuleNotFoundError: No module name 'cv'

Comment: what about `python3 -c "import cv"`

Comment: wait. I thought you said that you were able to install cv? Then why are you getting "No matching distribution found for cv"?

Comment: 'python3' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: It installed yesterday ok, not sure why I got that message.

Comment: when i type "python -c "import geopy" "   I get no errors or message

Comment: That is good. Means geopy should be correctly installed for your python version

Comment: could you run `python --version`?

Comment: I get Python 3.6.4

Comment: Does it also include Anaconda somewhere in the output?

Comment: No, only "Python 3.6.4"

Comment: Could it be that you have different python distributions installed? Could you run `where python`?

Comment: You might be onto something there. I had Python installed before I installed Anaconda. Anyway, that command returned a single path stmt  C:\Users\...

Comment: As long as the result of `where` didn't point to the Anaconda installation, then your path is set incorrectly. You have another python distribution installed. Since it is set before your Anaconda, when you do pip install, it installs for that other distribution instead of the Anaconda one. Then if you rund Jupyter, which uses the Anaconda installation, it cannot find the packages

Comment: Where you able to solve your problem? If so, feel free to accept my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did some search. There is no package cv in the package index. You need `pip install opencv-python` after which you can do `import cv2`

Edit based on comments: make sure that Anaconda is set before any other python distribution in your PATH before running `pip install`

Comment: Thx, that returned: Requirement already satisfied: ...   But back in Jupyter i get the same error message  ... No module named 'cv2'